# How to solve an error when import tensorrt using colab

Tags: import, tensorrt

When trying to import tensorrt I get the message:

> ImportError: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Verifying the installation shows:

> ...
>
> ii  tensorrt  7.0.0.11-1+cuda10.2   amd64   Meta package of TensorRT
>   ...

So I would assume that the installation has worked.
Since I have tried some solutions I have found and still can get it working I post this issue here.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed the following packages:

1. `libnvinfer` installed by `sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer`
2. `libnvinfer-dev` installed by `sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev`

For complete installation guide, please [visit](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had done so but nonetheless the import does not work. Error message is: "ImportError: libnvrtc.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" - I think a solution is to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH or symlink but yet I haven made it to get pathes/arguments right